# XPath Statement to select a string within &nbsp;

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to parse through and html page and pull certain values from the page.  I seem to be stuck on the last and final part of my code where I am trying to pull the value for the price of the item. The specific page I am looking at is http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys-duck-decoys-c-16_71.html.
This is the section I am working with that includes the price of $119.99.

```
<td align="center" class="productListing-data" width="25%">&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/dakota-decoys-dakota-decoy-full-body
-mallard-decoys-6pack-p-3036.html"><img src="images/DAK-12160-125.png" border="0"
alt="Dakota Decoy Full Body Mallard Decoys, 6-Pack" title=" Dakota Decoy Full 
Body Mallard Decoys, 6-Pack "></a>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.rogerssport
inggoods.com/dakota-decoys-dakota-decoy-full-body-mallard-decoys-6pack-p-3036.html
">Dakota Decoy Full Body Mallard Decoys, 6-Pack</a>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;DAK-12160&nbsp;
<br>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/dakota-decoys-m-200.html">
Dakota Decoys</a>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;$119.99&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/-s-.html"></a>&nbsp;</td>
```

Below is the code that I am currently using for this project:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from test_scraper.items import TestScraperItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["rogerssportinggoods.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys-duck-decoys-c-16_71.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        titles = hxs.select("//html/body/div/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td")
        for titles in titles:
            title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            price = titles.select("/a[text()='${nbsp}']").extract()
            print title, link, price
```

Comment: Please format your code for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "rogers"
    allowed_domains = ["rogerssportinggoods.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/decoys-duck-decoys-c-16_71.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        for box in hxs.select('descendant::table[@class="productListing"]//td'):
            title = box.select("a[2]/text()").extract()
            link = box.select("a[3]/@href").extract()
            price = [p.strip() for p in box.select("a[3]/following-sibling::node()").extract() if '$' in p]
            print title, link, price
```

Yields:

```
[u'Dakota Decoy Full Body Mallard Decoys, 6-Pack']
[u'http://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/dakota-decoys-m-200.html']
[u'$119.99']
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Is there any type of documentation on how you came up with that solution?  Not sure I quite fully understand everything in your solution.

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials for XPath and the only other piece of magic I put in there is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  If you want even more magic, try [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html).